# Play sound *on* remote machine via ssh on Ubuntu / Linux

Tags: linux, ssh, audio

I want to play sound on a remote machine via SSH, without X11 involvement. This should work regardless if a user is logged in to the console or X or not.

Basically, after logging in via ssh, a command line like

```
mpg123 test.mp3
```

should play the test.mp3 on this remote machine. In other words, a poor man's PA system. I allowed passwordless audio access via the network in the paprefs panel, but still no sound when I try to play via ssh.

What's the simplest and most reliable way to achieve this?

PS: Questions from the past have low-quality answers which don't answer this.

Comment: Just to clarify, are you able to play sounds when accessed directly via the console?

Comment: It seems that the [Music Player Deamon](http://www.musicpd.org/) is meant for this but I haven't tried it.

Comment: I have no problem whenn ssh into a remote debian machine and use `mpg123` to play a music file remotely. So probably you have to include more informations about your setup.

Comment: @krowe: Yes, I can play sounds just fine via the console. MPD could be a solution, if it is able to play on-the-fly generated files.

Comment: @mpy: My setup is Ubuntu 14.10 on both ends. I'll try a debian livecd to see what happens. In Ubuntu, the remote machine remains silent, while playing via console works fine.

But I am kind of stuck with Ubuntu here...

Comment: @mpy: @gmoshkin's answer made me revisit the question. Sound works in the special cases of the same user logged in to both machines, but not if this is not the case. I agree now with @krowe - you need a daemon like `mpd` for this to work. It is more complex than it seemed.

Comment: No, you don't need a daemon for it to work. It's very likely a problem with permissions, e.g. if you are running Pulseaudio. With the right permissions, you can play sounds on the remote machine via `ssh` just fine. So update your question with information about how your system is configured (Pulseaudio), which errors you get, etc. Also, first try to play WAV sounds via `aplay` (ALSA) or `paplay` (Pulseaudio), that's easier to debug. Note the errors you get.

Comment: @dirkt: `pactl list short sinks` shows only the null sink, with `aplay` or `paplay` quietly directing their output to. How should a PA config look like to make sound happen?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With recent Ubuntu systems (17.10 in this case), it is necessary to run `pulseaudio` at system start or manually to get audio via ssh. `pulseaudio` is started on a per-user basis as default, so if nobody is logged in, you only get the null sink for your SSH login, where all audio vanishes quietly.

For a permanent solution, a systemd service could be created:

```
cat <<EOF >/etc/systemd/system/pulseaudio.service
[Unit]
Description=Pulse Audio

[Service]
Type=simple
ExecStart=/usr/bin/pulseaudio --system --disallow-exit --disable-shm --exit-idle-time=-1

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
EOF
```

which makes sure that the pulseaudio daemon is started as the user pulse at startup. [Since this is highly discouraged by the developers](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/PulseAudio/Documentation/User/WhatIsWrongWithSystemWide/), the preferred solution for temporary use should be to issue `sudo pulseaudio --system -D` via SSH.

If a pulseaudio instance is already running, it should be killed to allow the new instance to discover the hardware. This impacts the audio for all logged-in users and should be handled on a case-by-case basis.

In any case, the logged-in user needs to be part of the pulse-access group:

```
sudo usermod -a -G pulse-access userName
```

Now it is possible to play sounds via SSH on the remote system (`mpg123`, `mpv` or others). Success can be checked by `pactl list short sinks` for proper audio sink detection.

Answer (score 6):

Setting the `DISPLAY` variable to `:0` solves the problem for me. Try running the command like this:

```
$ DISPLAY=:0 mpg123 test.mp3
```

Comment: A clever solution, but only for special case - the same user logged into both machines. If there is no user logged in or another user, you'll get `Invalid MIT-MAGIC-COOKIE-1 keyxcb_connection_has_error() returned true`.   I don't see a solution unless you have a daemon running for the moment. Upvoted nonetheless, may help others with this special case.